# Autoresizing anchors don't set the subviews to corners

Tags: ios, swift

I'm experiencing a problem using anchors in swift to resize my `UIButton` and `UILabel`.

My view right now:

[image: My view right now]

I want to the label and button to fill the whole view and leave leave an empty space ("openspace") in between. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class standardLabel: UIView {

    private var label: UILabel!
    private var button: UIButton!

    let openSpace: CGFloat = 4.0

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        label = UILabel()
        button = UIButton()

        label.backgroundColor = cLightBlue
        label.textColor = cWhite
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = fBigFont
        button.backgroundColor = cWhite
        button.setTitleColor(cDarkBlue, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = fBigCleanFont

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(button)

        setConstraints()

        //layer.masksToBounds = true
        //layer.cornerRadius = cornerRad
        backgroundColor = UIColor.brown//superview?.backgroundColor
    }

    func setTextLabel(text: String) -> Void {
        label.text = text
    }

    func setTextButton(text: String) -> Void {
        button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
    }

    private func setConstraints() -> Void {
        let margins = layoutMarginsGuide

        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true


        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: openSpace).isActive = true
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Did I make a mistake setting up the anchors or did it generate a problem because I created a separate class?

Comment: How are you adding this to view Controller?

Comment: I have a viewcontroller with a uiscrollview inside. In the scrollview I inserted a seperate view with an outlet and initialized it as a "standardlabel". Do you understand or do you want me to send a screenshot of my setup?

Comment: If you do not want to see the brown parts, use self instead of layoutMarginsGuide.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is perfectly fine, I just found that there is 4.0 between the two view but since the color of button is white you are not able to see the spacing between the label and the button.

Try to increase the spacing to 20.0, you'll know the difference.

Comment: I've tried it and it does work perfectly fine. The problem was setting the constraints to `self` instead to `self.layoutMarginsGuide`. Now the `UILabel` and `UIButton` fill the while view! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Setting the anchors equal to `self` instead of `self.layoutMarginsGuide` will fix the problem.